# Custom Name for `information_schema` database

Tags: sql, mariadb

Is there a way to modify the SQL server to give the virtual `information_schema` database a different name by default?

Or is `information_schema` a standard so that software knows where to look and query for information?

I'm using 10.5.15-MariaDB - MariaDB Server

I'd like to rename it to .information_schema so that the database doesn't show up in the middle of the databases list on my CMS.

I don't have control over hiding/displaying databases by name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

information_schema cannot be modified or deleted.
If I were you, I would avoid any attempt to modify the default databases.
Here is what I found searching similar questions:

> INFORMATION_SCHEMA is a database within each MySQL instance, the place
> that stores information about all the other databases that the MySQL
> server maintains. The INFORMATION_SCHEMA database contains several
> read-only tables. They are actually views, not base tables, so there
> are no files associated with them, and you cannot set triggers on
> them. Also, there is no database directory with that name.
> *([source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/233642/is-it-safe-to-delete-preinstalled-mysql-databases-like-information-schema#:%7E:text=The%20INFORMATION_SCHEMA%20database%20contains%20several,t%20attempt%20to%20delete%20them.))